# How to generate a 3D geometry given 3 3D points?

Tags: 3d, three.js, geometry

I'm developing a function that would let a user select 3 points from a point cloud, generate a 3D geometry (hexahedron) that includes those 3D points and then get the volume of that geometry.

The functionality I'm trying to achieve is very similar to the **volume measure** function from [this demo](http://demo.orbitgis.com/moma/). Any ideas on how do I generate that 3D geometry? Thanks.

Comment: Three points don't define a cube. Are you looking for an *axis-aligned* cube containing your three points?

Comment: @MvG I suppose, currently I'm using a function of the Box3 class of three.js library that returns a box that envelops a set of given points and it does the job, more or less.

Comment: You mean `Box3.setFromPoints`?

Comment: @MvG exactly, do you think it is a decent way to achieve the funcitonality I described?

Comment: So what is it you want? Reimplement the functionality of `Box3.setFromPoints` yourself? Use something different to better match your (not clearly expressed) requirements? Find the appropriate points from the cloud based on 2D user input? Compute the volume of the resulting box?

Comment: @MvG my goal for now is to find the 3D box that would best fit the input points selected by the user, I think it would be the minimum bounding-box. I'm not sure if the `Box3.setFromPoints` computes the minimum bounding-box but I'm gonna stick with it as its results are quite decent. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [`Box3`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Box3) called `b` then you can get its volume like this:

```
var v = b.max.sub(b.min);
return v.x*v.y*v.z;
```

The box is axis-aligned, so its volume is its the product of its extent along each of the three coordinate axes. The extent is the difference between `max` and `min`.

*This is untested, purely read from the documentation.*